# How do I recover the disk space space after uninstalling Ethereum Wallet on OS/X?

Tags: wallets, mac-osx

Just to preface, I am somewhat new to Ethereum, and I'm trying to learn my way around.

So I recently downloaded the Ethereum Wallet from the Ethereum website, and I subsequently uninstalled it once I realized that it was downloading the entire blockchain, which I just don't have space for on my machine (on a mac).

However, I noticed that I am missing about 9 gigs of space on my machine even after deleting the app and the data. Any idea why I'm missing space? Any files I should delete?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On OS/X, Ethereum Wallet places the blockchain data in the `chaindata` subdirectory under `$HOME/Library/Ethereum/geth`.

You can remove the `chaindata` subdirectory.

If you want to save any private/public keys, copy `$HOME/Library/Ethereum/keystore` and it's contents to a backup location.

If you have no use for Ethereum Wallet on your computer, you can remove the data from your computer (after saving your keystore if necessary) by deleting `$HOME/Library/Ethereum` and it's contents.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It's very odd, but I did all those things and I'm still missing like 9 gigs of space. Really bizarre. Thank you though.

Comment: Have you emptied your Trash folder?

Comment: Yes... It's really bizarre.

Comment: Start terminal. Go to $HOME/Library . Type `du -hs *` to find the large directory. Go into the large directories and use the same commands to find where the large files are. If you cannot still find where the space went, start at '/' .

Comment: A little late to the game, but after deleting large files from mac, I learned that if one uses time machine, its local cache can be cleared to recover space.
e.g. 
"sudo tmutil disablelocal"  

watch your disk space drop, then switch it back on  

"sudo tmutil enablelocal"

Comment: @belwood, I'll have to check this out. Thx

Comment: but it still opening previous mist

Answer (score 1):

You'll also want to get rid of the application support folder.  This will take care it of all:
`rm -rf ~/Library/Ethereum && rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Ethereum\ Wallet`